# Jquery - .offset().left() - percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relativeX = e.pageX - offset.left;
```

This return value of pixels..

How do, return value of percentage?

Answer (score 2):

If you get the width of the element you want to get the percentage from.

html:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click','.test', function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relativeX = e.pageX - offset.left;
    var wide = $('body').width();
    var percent = (relativeX*100)/wide;
    alert(percent);
});
```

CSS:

```
.test{
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

[See it live here](http://liveweave.com/wVH9iu).

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).offset().top` and `$(this).offset().left` return integers and your `e.pageX` I will asume it is an integer. In this case you can't. You can then get the percentage the substraction of these values represent but the operation `var relativeX = e.pageX - offset.left;` will return an integer.